# How to use vector sort by attribute when class is private (inaccessible)?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a .h file with a class and inside the class 
public:
- are the methods
private:
- a class.

```
class Trendtracker
{   
public:

    Trendtracker();

    void insert(string ht);

    int size();

    void tweeted(string ht);

    int popularity(string name);

    string top_trend();

    void trending(int k, vector<string> &T);

private:

    class Entry
    {
    public:
        string hashtag;
        int pop;

        //This is what I would use if I was allowed to edit the .h
        //bool operator< (const Entry &other) const {
        //    return pop > other.pop;
        //}
    };

    vector<Entry> E;
};
```

The thing is I am not allowed to access the .h file. 
In the .cpp file (this is the only file I am allowed to edit), I am trying to sort by an attribute of the `vector<Entry>`.

The code snippet in the .cpp that, has the `std::sort()`
The name of the file is Trendtracker.h and Trendtracker.cpp

```
string Trendtracker::top_trend(){
    if(E.size()==0){
        return "";
    }
    sort(E.begin(), E.end());
    return E[0].hashtag;
}
```

What can I do, to not edit the .h file and instead create the `bool operator<` in the .cpp because when I try I get that I cannot access pop because `vector<Trendtracker::Entry>` is private. Or the error that the variable does not exist in `Trendtracker`.
One of the things I have tried is:

```
struct myclass {
    bool operator() (int i,int j, Trendtracker::Entry &E) { 
        return (E[i].pop<E[j].pop);
    }
} myobject;
```

Here the error I get is 1. That Entry is a private member of `Trendtracker` and 2. that `Trendtracker::Entry` does not provide a subscript.
If I try

```
sort(E.begin(), E.end(), E.pop);
```

I get the error:

> No member named 'pop' in `'std::__1::vector<Trendtracker::Entry, std::__1::allocator<Trendtracker::Entry> >'`

I was wondering what I could do to get this to work. An explanation that explains exactly why would be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, sorry about the formatting issues.

Comment: `std::sort(E.begin(), E.end(), [](const Entry& a, const Entry& b) { return /* whether a should precede b */; } );`

Comment: @Liam In the future, here are 2 things to follow when posting code: 1. Make sure there's a blank line before and after the code you paste in. 2. Rather than trying to make the code formatting yourself, select the code that you pasted in, and type Ctrl+K, or else press the `{}` button. This properly applies the formatting. (alternatively, if you know the keyboard shortcut to increase the indentation in your editor (often `Ctrl+]` or just `Tab` with the code selected), you can use that before you post the code in)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the comparator inside `top_trend` my help, like this

```
string Trendtracker::top_trend(){
    if(E.size()==0){
        return "";
    }
    struct myclass {
        bool operator() (const Entry &a const Entry &b) { 
            return (a.pop<b.pop);
        }
    } myobject;
    sort(E.begin(), E.end(), myobject);
    return E[0].hashtag;
}
```

or use lambda like @Igor [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373728/how-to-use-vector-sort-by-attribute-when-class-is-private-inaccessible/48374686#comment83734700_48373728),

```
std::sort(E.begin(), E.end(), [](const Entry& a, const Entry& b) { return /* whether a should precede b */; } );
```